# difference between creating an array in a constructor vs in main

Tags: arrays, constructor

If I have a class called game and a private: char board[3][3], how come I cannot initialize the array with the method below?

`board[3][3]={'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' }`

In the main, I can initiate arrays using the above method but not in my class?

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        board[i][j]='a';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In basic language `board[3][3]` means you are creating a 2D array i.e. array of an array as there is no such thing like a 2D array for the compiler. The compiler sees it as on each index of the 1D array there is another array. So when you write `board[3][3]={'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' }` gives error because
1. You are initializing the array but `char board[3][3]` is only a reference so memory of for size 3  will not be allocated to allocate it you have to use the **new** keyword in java as `char board[][] = new char[3][3]{{'a','a','a'},{'a','a','a'}'{'a','a','a'}};`
2.you are declaring the 2D array but you are not mentioning the column values, so if you will write `board[][]={'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' }` this will also be an error, hence to separate each row and column value make them in `{'a','a','a'}` i.e., `board[][]={{'a', 'a', 'a'},{'a', 'a', 'a'},{'a', 'a', 'a'}}`.